# how to get the Seconds of the time using python

Tags: python, time

this is my code:

```
last_time = get_last_time()
now = time.time() - last_time
minute = 
seconds = 
print 'Next time you add blood is '+minute+':'+seconds
```

Because recovery blood every 5 minutes so only need minute and second

thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is basic time arithmetics...if you know that a minute has 60 seconds then you could
have found that yourself:

```
minute = int(now / 60)
seconds = int(now % 60)
```

Comment: This is correct, but "now" is a rather unintuitive name. Change it to "remaining_secs" or something like that.

Comment: We don't have other problems? tell that to OP

Comment: Sorry, I meant to address the OP. :) But I can see why you may have felt offended.

Comment: This answer is also wrong, because a minute does not have to have 60 seconds

Comment: @PaulSmith Good point. I edited it again to cast to int. Modulus can also be a decimal value if the input is (which it is in this case), so now I cast that to int as well.

Comment: @Zecc You should delete your comment then, instead of adding more.

Comment: A modulo returns the remainder. So to get seconds it would be `seconds = int(now - (now % 60))`

Answer (score 8):

I believe the difference between two time objects returns a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object. This object has a `.total_seconds()` method. You'll need to factor these into minutes+seconds yourself:

```
minutes = total_secs % 60
seconds = total_secs - (minutes * 60)
```

When you don't know what to do with a value in Python, you can always try it in an interactive Python session. Use `dir(obj)` to see all of any object's attributes and methods, `help(obj)` to see its documentation.

**Update**: I just checked and `time.time()` doesn't return a `time` object, but a floating point representing seconds since Epoch. What I said still applies, but you get the value of `total_secs` in a different way:

```
total_secs = round(time.time() - last_time)
```

So in short:

```
last_time = get_last_time()
time_diff = round(time.time() - last_time)
minute = time_diff / 60
seconds = time_diff % 60  # Same as time_diff - (minutes * 60)
print 'Next time you add blood is '+minute+':'+seconds
```

Comment: Nonsense - time.time() just returns a float. >>> time.time()
1305803305.7057121
>>> type(time.time())
<type 'float'>

Comment: @Sentinel Yeah, I just checked and updated my answer in the meantime. I also upvoted your answer, since it is correct. I feel tempted to remove my answer, but I'll leave it just in case zjm1126 wants to copy the code from it.

Comment: timedelta.total_seconds() is Python 2.7 and up.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3,

```
>>import time
>>time.localtime()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=16, tm_hour=1, tm_min=51, tm_sec=39, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=197, tm_isdst=0)
```

You can scrape the minutes and seconds like that,

```
>>time.localtime().tm_min
51
>>time.localtime().tm_sec
39
```

I think, this can solve your problem.