# How to get only the seconds offset from timezone

Tags: python

Might seem very easy for others but I couldn't find a way to get only the seconds from the timezone

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dstr = '2017-06-20T19:40+02:00'
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> dt = parse(dstr)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 20, 19, 40, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))
```

How to get only the 7200 (with - sign as well for negative, if it is negative) from the tzoffset object? I couldn't find the documentation for the tzoffset in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the Seconds of the time using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057379/how-to-get-the-seconds-of-the-time-using-python)

Comment: @marmeladze: not seconds of the datetime, seconds of the *timezone*.

Comment: Why would this generate a negative sign when the offset is positive?

Comment: @EdChum for this date string '2017-06-20T19:40-02:00' the tzoffset is tzoffset(None, -7200) . So I expected that the offset will be represented as negative number -7200. But seems that the result from this using the answer below is : dt.tzinfo._offset.seconds => 79200 (86400 - 7200)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timezone is a separate object from the `dateutil` project, see [`dateutil.tz.offset`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html?highlight=tzoffset#dateutil.tz.tzoffset):

```
>>> dt.tzinfo
tzoffset(None, 7200)
>>> type(dt.tzinfo)
<class 'dateutil.tz.tz.tzoffset'>
```

The official API is to use the [`tzinfo.utcoffset()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.utcoffset), passing in the `datetime` instance:

```
>>> dt.tzinfo.utcoffset(dt)
datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
>>> dt.tzinfo.utcoffset(dt).seconds
7200
```

The documentation doesn't specify any attributes for the `dateutil.tz.offset` object; it is not designed for direct interrogation. If you don't want to use the `tzinfo.utcoffset()` method, then `dir()` reveals what we can access:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dir(dt.tzinfo))
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_name',
 '_offset',
 'dst',
 'fromutc',
 'is_ambiguous',
 'tzname',
 'utcoffset']
```

The `_offset` attribute is a `datetime.timedelta()` object:

```
>>> dt.tzinfo._offset
datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
>>> dt.tzinfo._offset.seconds
7200
```

The attribute is an *implementation detail*, so be careful not to rely too much on it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work as well :

```
dt.tzinfo.utcoffset(dt).total_seconds()
Out[23]: 7200.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
dstr = '2017-06-20T19:40+02:00'
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse(dstr)
print(dt.timetz().utcoffset().seconds)
7200
```

detail see: [time.tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.time.tzinfo)